# Why does my header force a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following desired layout:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| +----------+                                                 |
| |          |                                                 |
| |  IMAGE   |                       HEADER TEXT ALIGNED RIGHT |
| |          |                                                 |
| +----------+                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here, a `#header` div has 2 children: an image and h1 text. The image needs to be aligned left, the h1 text right. The h1 text should be in the vertical center of the `#header` div:

```
<style>
  #header { width: 100%; }
  #header img { float: left; }
  #header h1 { display: block; float: right; }
</style>

<div id="header">
  <img src="logo.gif">
  <h1>HEADER TEXT ALIGNED RIGHT</h1>
</div>
```

This, however, gives me a horizontal scrollbar in the browser. If I define the `#header h1` width as, for instance, 500px, the horizontal scrollbar disappears. However, this since I want a fluid layout, I do not want to define a fixed with for any div.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't get a horizontal scrollbar with what you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/2wqBA/

Comment: I dont see what you mean with the scroll bar http://jsfiddle.net/VtLpZ/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that margin, padding, etc properties of body element is 0. If you want to maintain these properties, the width of #header element should be set to `auto` or leave it ``.
That means,

```
#header{width:auto;}
```